# R in quantmod error

Tags: r, quantmod

x=read.csv(file.choose())

head(x)

```
  Date     Open  High  Low   Close Volume
1 2013/1/2 13257 13289 13162 13194 168353
2 2013/1/3 13195 13198 13055 13055 242457
3 2013/1/4 13050 13100 13005 13079 256215
4 2013/1/7 13085 13128 13025 13126 228488
5 2013/1/8 13136 13148 13064 13088 227064
6 2013/1/9 13091 13104 13044 13072 219862
```

library(quantmod)

barChart(x)

Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
  chartSeries requires an xtsible object

Comment: Could you explain a bit more clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Convert `x` to xts, or to a data.frame that works with `as.xts`.

Comment: step1.write .zoo step2. as.xts

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line. Assuming the file you are loading is named "spy.csv" in your "data" directory, holding SP500 OHLC data.

```
spy <-as.xts(read.zoo("~/data/spy.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",colClasses = c("Date", rep("numeric",4))))

barChart(SPY)
```

will show you the chart in all it's glory :-)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the file name is GSPC, BY loading the solution we will get !!

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
In file(file, "rt") :
 cannot open file 'GSPC.csv': No such file or directory ====> my file is existed !!!
```